# What protection certificates would be required for an application that consists of setup, loading utility and main application?

Tags: windows, antivirus, digital-signature, code-signing

Say we have an InnoSetup installer script, a native C++ QT files loading application and a .Net client application that we load/update each time and which is the main application. We load files via http post\get requests.

So how many different certificates would our application need to prove for antivirus protectors that we are indeed a real not virus application and which part of our application would require which certificates?

Comment: To whoever downvoted: please explain your reasons for doing so. OP learns nothing if you remain silent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have one code signing certificate. You should sign every binary with this certificate. So, for example, the generated installer EXE would be signed. If the C++ downloader application is included in the installer, you wouldn't technically need to sign it, but while you're at it, do it anyways.

The .net client app needs to be signed, and the application that downloads the .net app **must** verify that whatever it downloaded is properly signed by **your** certificate (not just any certificate).

You may want to run the download via HTTPS (remember to properly verify the SSL certificates, including checking the CN which is often forgotten) as an additional layer of security.

Note that this has little to do with Antivirus vendors. They may have less strict heuristics for signed files (thus sign everything), but the main reason for signing is to prevent attacks.